# smart pointer - what if constructor throws?

Tags: c++, constructor, auto-ptr

I have a class that connects to a USB device in the constructor. If the device isn't present or some other situation fails then the constructor throws an exception and the calling code deals with it.

Something akin to:

```
CDevice* pDevice = NULL;
try
{
    pDevice = new CDevice();
}
```

and so on. I would like to replace this call with an `auto_ptr` but am not clear how to trap the exception while maintaining the correct scope of the object.

Comment: If you're using C++11, `auto_ptr` is deprecated. If C++03, there's still TR1 and Boost.

Comment: you want to inspect the object after its constructor throw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I recommend you don't use `auto_ptr`, it's somewhat broken and has been deprecated in C++11. Prefer either Boost or C++11 SBRM classes like `std::unique_ptr`. You can do this without much modification to your example.

```
std::unique_ptr<CDevice> pDevice;
try
{
    pDevice.reset(new CDevice());
}
catch(...)
{
    //....
}
```

If `new` or the constructor of `CDevice` throws then pDevice will remain empty. Using `auto_ptr` isn't much different, just not recommended given the available alternatives.

```
std::auto_ptr<CDevice> pDevice;

try
{
    pDevice.reset(new CDevice());

    //pDevice = std::auto_ptr<CDevice>(new CDevice());
    // ^^ historical masochism. 
}
catch(...)
{
    //....
}
```

Comment: Seems like I will have an unhandled exception in the first creation of the pointer now.

Comment: @ethrbunny: the default constructor is explicitly noexcept, meaning it will never ever throw.

Comment: Hmm. I'd love to try this but the recommended '-std=c++0x' option isn't recognized on my system. (CentOS 6.2)

Comment: @ethrbunny I've included an example for `auto_ptr` that should get be what you're looking for.

Comment: Your auto_ptr example could use the `reset()` method as well.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` is a perfectly good class, just understand what it does and don't misuse it!

Comment: @ethrbunny catches himself abusing `auto_ptr` already. Dang. That didn't take long.